# Live feed of values from a database Qt

Tags: c++, database, qt, feed, live

I am writing an application on Qt that is constantly checking for data change on certain table using a QSqlQueryModel calling a query to retrieve the last value inserted on the database and comparing the timestamp in the row to the pervious value checked. I check every 100 ms using a timer calling a method which emits a signal telling that the data was changed or not. That however, creates a massive load on the processor sometimes rendering the computer useless until I close the app. I am only testing the performace of the platform for I need to implement it to many other tables in the same database and app in order to display the values on a sort of 'live' feed related to every table. I have read about Threads, but haven't really got a clue on how to implement it. Is there another way of doing this? What would you recomend me?

Comment: Are you able to set this up as an event and register your application for notifications from the database on an update?  Generally, events are a good alternative for this kind of polling.

Comment: @user1161318 I changed the database engine, from mysql to postgresql which has a built-in notification system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your query takes more than 100ms to perform, so you are basically overloading the database with queries, stacking them on top of each other while the previous ones haven't finished.

Do **not** use the restarting timer from QTimer, but a single-shot timer. Restart the timer only after your query has finished in your slot.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my aproach and switch to a different database server, I am now using postgresql using a trigger as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION notification_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$

DECLARE

BEGIN
 execute 'NOTIFY ' || TG_RELNAME || '_' || TG_OP;
 return new;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then just call the trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sometable_trigger BEFORE insert or update or delete on table1 
execute procedure notification_trigger();
```

Hope it helps someone.